# Binding specific item of a ListModel to a Component

Tags: qt, haskell, qml, hsqml

I am building an application with HsQML. This is my first encounter with QML, my second ever work in Qt, and first larger project with Haskell, so forgive my ignorance.

In the UI, I have a TabView. The first Tab contains a ListView which is bound to a model and displays a list of items. Double-clicking an item in the ListView opens a new tab with a component which correctly shows that item's details (my guess is by virtue of the new tab inheriting its context from the list item that was clicked).

Now, my objective is to open a tab in which to create a new item for that model. The idea is to create a blank data item (optionally adding it to the model), and "load" this into the same component type used for editing existing items. I scoured QML's documentation and could not find anything even remotely related, which makes me think the approach is completely flawed.

```
TabView {
    id : rootTabs

    Tab {
        ListView {
            model : AutoListModel {
                source : workflowModel // this is sort of HsQML specific, data comes as a list from Haskell
            }
            delegate : Rectangle {
                Text {
                    text : modelData.name
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill : parent

                    // this part works because the new component inherits its modelData from the current context
                    // so the new tab has correct data
                    onDoubleClicked : {
                        rootTabs.addTab(modelData.name, Qt.createComponent("WorkflowView.qml"))
                        rootTabs.currentIndex = rootTabsCount - 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            text : "Create workflow"

            // this is the part in question - how do I assign the newly appended data to comp?
            onClicked : {
                wModel.appendBlank()
                comp = Qt.createComponent("WorkflowView.qml")
                var tab = rootTabs.addTab("New workflow", comp)
                comp.statusChanged.connect(tabLoaded)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WorkflowEdit.qml:

```
Rectangle {
    TextField {
        id : nameInput
        text : modelData.name
        Binding {
            target : modelData
            property : "name"
            value : nameInput.text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the new tab has correct data? It looks like you're just creating a WorkflowView component and that's it. Can you post the code for that qml file?

Comment: Correct, I am just creating a WorkflowView. However, when creating it from a double-click on a ListView item, its modelData seems to contain that item's corresponding data... which is complete magic.


Now, I would like to be able to do the same programatically, so that `WorkflowView`'s `modelData` will refer to an item from the model that I want.

Added an example WorkflowView, which is really quite simple anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have what you're looking for. It was a little tricky because Tab are essentially loaders. It was a matter of creating an extra property for the Tab QML type as a place to store a model index. And since tabs are simply children of a TabView, new tabs can be parented to the TabView instead of using the addTab() method. Note that for my model I used a ListModel.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    TabView {
        id : rootTabs
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListModel {
            id: listModel
            ListElement { car: "Toyota" }
            ListElement { car: "Chevrolet" }
            ListElement { car: "Honda" }
            ListElement { car: "Daihatsu" }
            ListElement { car: "Ford" }
            ListElement { car: "Nissan" }
            ListElement { car: "Hyundai" }
            ListElement { car: "Acura" }
        }

        MyTab {
            title: "Default"

            Item {

                ListView {
                    id: listView
                    anchors { fill: parent; bottomMargin: 240 }
                    model : listModel

                    delegate : Rectangle {
                        width: parent.width
                        height: 40
                        Text {
                            text : car
                            color: "black"
                            font.pointSize: 20
                        }

                        MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill : parent
                            onDoubleClicked : {
                                var myTab = Qt.createComponent("MyTab.qml")
                                var workflow = Qt.createComponent("Workflow.qml")
                                myTab.createObject(rootTabs, { "title": car, "modelIndex": index, "sourceComponent": workflow });
                                rootTabs.currentIndex = rootTabs.count - 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Button {
                    anchors {fill: parent; topMargin: 240 }
                    text : "Create workflow"

                    onClicked : {
                        listModel.append( { "car" : "New car" } )
                        var myTab = Qt.createComponent("MyTab.qml")
                        var workflow = Qt.createComponent("Workflow.qml")
                        myTab.createObject(rootTabs, { "title": "New Workflow", "modelIndex": listModel.count - 1 , "sourceComponent": workflow });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyTab.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Tab {
    property int modelIndex
}
```

**Workflow.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Rectangle {
    TextField {
        id : nameInput
        text : listModel.get(modelIndex).car
        onTextChanged: {
            // Update model using modelIndex. Observe updates in listview
            listModel.set(modelIndex, { "car" : text })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it! Seems there were two gotchas - **1)** setting properties on the tab's item after creation was not working properly, so using `createObject` manually worked around that. The proper solution to this imo is to expose the same configuration to `addTab` that `addObject` takes (and probably it's being called behind the scenes anyhow. **2)** Assigning an arbitrary object to a property failed. I wonder whether this has to do with me using HsQML and not creating `QObject`s myself. The workaround was to set an index into the model on an `int` property and look that up every time.

Answer (score 2):

`TabView::addTab` returns a `Tab` object, which is basically a `Loader` object. `Loader::item` is the current loaded object. So, the solution is to add an new empty model data to the tab as follows (in Button::onClicked):

```
var tab = ...
tab.loaded.connect(function () {tab.item.data = newModelData;}); // newModelData = wModel.appendBlank() ???
```

And you should add the property modelData explicitly to WorkflowEdit.qml:

```
Rectangle {
    property var data: modelData // create property data and assign the context variable modelData to it by default
    TextField {
        id : nameInput
        text : data === undefined ? "" : data.name
        Binding {
            target : data
            property : "name"
            value : nameInput.text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this both in the creating function, and in the tab's `statusChanged` handler, getting `Error: Cannot assign to non-existent property "modelData"`. Also tried assigning to `component.modelData` instead of the tab - this does not show an error, but doesn't work nevertheless, modelData continues to be undefined in WorkflowView.

Comment: I extended my answer to resolve your raised problem.

Comment: Darn, I see how this should solve the undefined property problem, but still not working :( I am getting a `QML WorkflowEditView: Binding loop detected for property "modelData"` (which as I understand is just a warning) and also   when I activate the tab: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. For the latter, as I mentioned already I tried setting the model both when creating the tab, and when the tab becomes ready, and neither works. Btw I assign to component.modelData, since the property is defined on the component and not the tab.

Comment: I changed three things: (1) renamed modelData to data to avoid naming conflicts (2) you definitely should set data on `tab.item` (not on `tab` or `component`) (3) checked if data is undefined to avoid warnings

Comment: Now I'm getting a rather generic `TypeError: Type error` on the line that assigns to `tab.item.data`. I guess this might have to do with the way I'm passing the data from the backend...

Comment: You can debug it using `console.log("New tab item: ", tab.item)` and `console.log("New model data: ", newModelData)`

Comment: Yes, tab.item is null and that's why the assignment fails. Tried it again during creation, and once the tab's `loaded` signal fires.

Comment: Well, I am still unable to set data on the WorkflowView, so no... I am kinda surprised there isn't just an `Item::setData` method or something along those lines. I'm sure there are reasons for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141251/discussion-between-recencyeffect-and-m7913d).